# Core Data: SortDescriptor based on first in to-many relationship

Tags: swift, core-data

I have an entity A that has an ordered to-many relationship to another entity B.

I'd like to sort a fetchrequest for A by a property (name) of the first (if available) B.

For example, I have

- A1 that is related to B.name = "Alice" and B.name = "Bob" and
- A2 that is related to B.name = "Eve"

Now I want to build a SortDescriptor that orders them by the name of the first B, i.e. A1, A2

Intuitively, I'd try to use

```
SortDescriptor(\A.relationship?.firstObject?.name)
```

but that doesn't compile (`Failed to produce diagnostic for expression;`).

Is this simply not possible or am I missing something?

Comment: That is not be possible to do in Core Data as far as I know.

Comment: Your included code implies you think that objects in a relationship are sorted which they aren't so the logic that is needed is something like this, for each A object sort the related B objects and select the first B then use this B object to sort all A objects. So it's a two step (at least) process that you will need to do in your swift code after the fetch request has been run.

Comment: @JoakimDanielson Thank you for taking the time to comment.It's an ordered relationship, so the elements are in an NSOrderedSet. 
To me it seems like the issue is that firstObject returns "Any", not "B", and I don't know if or how casting would be possible for a keypath.

Comment: Ok but is NSOrderedSet really relevant here? Or does the app make sure the order of the set is always in alphabetical order on name? Either way I assume, I haven't used it much myself, that there is no SQL functionality corresponding to NSOrderedSet so you can't use it in a FetchRequest anyway.

Comment: Yes, the order is relevant and it's not computable (user defined order). I've just given up on using FetchRequests for this and am now instead sorting the FetchResults via .sorted(by:)